# How can I to have only one touch event in android

Tags: android

How can I to have only one touch event in android? this is my code. the minimum API is API 7.

```
a.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getX(0)>=20 && event.getY(0)>=60 && event.getX(0)<=160 && event.getY(0)<=150) {
            B b = new B(getApplicationContext());
            relativeLayout.addView(b);
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: You mean, support only single finger touch?

Comment: Yes.I mean that it supports single finger touch.

Comment: I added another method to my answer. Maybe you'll prefer that approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is never going to use multi-touch features, I suggest you use the following in your theme

```
<item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
<item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
```

This will disable multi-touch for your entire app, unless you have multiple themes which you choose and apply programmatically in your `Activities`.

EDIT:

If you do not prefer the above approach, or if your app requires multi-touch capabilities, use the code below to disable multi-touch for just a particular view.

```
private boolean viewAlreadyTouched = false;

a.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if(viewAlreadyTouched) {
                return true;
            } else {
                viewAlreadyTouched = true;
                if (event.getX(0)>=20 && event.getY(0)>=60 && event.getX(0)<=160 && event.getY(0)<=150) {
                    B b = new B(getApplicationContext());
                    relativeLayout.addView(b);
                }
                return true;
           }
           break;

           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
               viewAlreadyTouched = false;
    }


}
```

});